# Parametrization of parabolic hyperboloid.

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

Please, help me! 
How I can parametrize this surface:

I have a parabolic hyperboloid. $ H := (z = xy) $ intersected by a cylinder whose base is a unit circle centered at the point $(0, 0, 1)$ I tried to use hyperboloic functions, paraboloic coordinates and e.t.c. The main difficulty for me is that I don't know how a cross-section of this surfaces looks like. Ok, maybe I can draw it, but it will not give me anything.

Also, if it is easier to find the projection on the coordinate planes than to find the parametrization, then it will even be enough for me to know the projection.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why I want this parametrization? Why it is better than parametrization in answer?

Comment: Sorry, incorrectly understood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the parameterization

$$
x = r\cos t\\
y = r\sin t\\
z = r^2\sin t\cos t
$$

for $0 \le t \lt 2\pi$ we get in blue for $r=1$

[image]

We have also for the area element

$$
dx dy \equiv r dr dt
$$

and the surface normal vector for $S(x,y,z) = z-x y = 0$

$$
\nabla S(x,y,z) = (-y,-x,1)\equiv (-r \sin t,-r \cos t, 1)
$$

Comment: After your edit I seems understood how I can find a flux.
For example: $\overline a = (1,2,3)$ (its boring, but for example it doesnt matter).

Then:
$\iint_{S} (\overline a \cdot \overline n)dS = \pm \iint_{S}dydz +2dzdx +3dxdy =
\pm \int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{2\pi}det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\frac{\partial x }{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}  & \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial x }{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}  & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}
\end{pmatrix} drd\phi = \pm 3\pi$

The normals define the sign. Anything higher is correct?

Comment: How will the parameterization change if the center of the cylinder base is changed? For example make the center of the cylinder the point $(1,0,0)$ 


We have: 
$x = 1+r\cos t\\
y = r\sin t\\
z = r^2\sin t\cos t$ ?

Comment: First note that $\vec n =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}(-r\sin t, -r\cos t,1)$ due to normalization (unit vector)

Comment: Second. In the answer I assumed a cylinder with main axis parallel to the $z$ axis. If maintaining this you make a translation in the main axis to the point $(1,0,0)$ then $x = 1+r\cos t, y = r \sin t, z=(1+r\cos t)(r\sin t)$

Comment: Thanks! What about a flux through this surface? My integration was right?